# Bluetooth 5 PHY layers (for all 4 modes)

Tags: physical-design, bluetooth-5

I am researching Bluetooth 5 for work and I cannot find anywhere the PHY layer of the different bluetooth modes (LE 1M (legacy Bluetooth 4), LE 2M (Double the Speed), LE Coded scheme 2 (2 x Range) & scheme 8 (4 x Range).

I know that LE 1M is IEEE 802.15.1.

This source (http://dev.ti.com/tirex/content/simplelink_cc2640r2_sdk_1_35_00_33/docs/ble5stack/ble_user_guide/html/ble-stack/phy-2mbps.html) says LE 2M is the same as LE 1M but with a different modulation. Would this make it still IEEE 802.15.1?

I haven't been able to find any sources that directly say if LE 2M, LE scheme 2 or scheme 8 are IEEE 802.15.1 or some other protocol. Any help is very appreciated, Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

BLE is not IEEE 802.15.1 at all.

The PHY layers in BLE are specified in the Bluetooth Core specification under "Low Energy Controller volume Part A Physical Layer specification" which can be found at https://www.bluetooth.com/specifications/bluetooth-core-specification/.